# Issue with updating state in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

There is a React component which contains list of users and form to invite a new user.

- "inviteNewUser" is a `*POST*` request in backend
- "getUsers" is a `*GET*` request to get all users

The problem is that after clicking on button "Invite User" I would like to see the invited user in the list of users ("`currentUsers`" in code below) without refreshing the page. But right now it happens only after I refresh the whole page.

when I'm trying to make a `GET` request to get all users right after `inviteNewUser(data)` (POST request) I'm getting the "old" user list without user which I just invited. So the "`currentUsers`" list is not immediately updated

Could someone help me to fix this issue ?

```js
 export function MyForm({
  getUsers,
  inviteNewUser,
  userId,
  currentUsers
  }) {

    useEffect(() => {
      getUsers(userId);
    }, [userId]);

  function handleSendInvite(data) {
    inviteNewUser(data);
    getUsers(data.userId);
  }

  return (
  <>
      {currentUsers.map((user) => (
        <UserItem
          key={user.userId}
          user={user}
        />
      ))}
      <Button
        text="Invite User"
        onClick={() => {
            handleSendInvite({userId});
        }}
      />
  </>);
}


MyForm.propTypes = {
  getUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  inviteNewUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  userId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  currentUsers: PropTypes.arrayOf(UserInfo),
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { id } = routerParamsSelector(state);
  const currentUsers = selectCurrentUsers(state);

  return {
    userId: parseInt(id, 10),
    currentUsers,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUsers,
  inviteNewUser
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try async and await, it works.

```
const handleSendInvite = async (data) {
  await inviteNewUser(data);
  getUsers(data.userId);
}
```

Comment: nope, unfortunately it doesnt work too

Answer (score 1):

It should be `user` instead of `userId` as you access the property of the object in the function.

```
 

<Button text="Invite User" onClick={() => { handleSendInvite(user); }} />
------------------------------------------------------------------------

const handleSendInvite = async (data) {
  await inviteNewUser(data);
  getUsers(data.userId);
}
```